# ¿Cómo hacer un cast de un *void a un struct en C?

Tags: c, funciones, punteros

Tengo un problema en C. Tengo un puntero tipo const void llamado p1, el cual a la hora de acceder a su valor me da errores. Se supone que es porque tengo que hacerlo tipo struct, pero no se hacer el cast para poder acceder a la estructura. Alguna solución o ejemplo de como hacer correctamente el cast de *void a struct? Los errores que me salen son del tipo:
warning: dereferencing 'void *' pointer in:
if(*p1 == *p2)

Gracias por adelantado.

```
/**
 * @brief Compares two points.
 * 
 * @param p1,p2 Points to compare.
 *
 * @return Returns True or False. 
 * In case of error, returns FALSE. 
 */
Bool point_equal (const void *p1, const void *p2){

    if(*p1 == *p2){
        return TRUE;
    }
    else{
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: `(struct tu_estructura *) p1`

Comment: ¿Podrías aportar la parte del código donde te da error? "Me da errores" no es una buena explicación, ¿puedes aportar qué tipo de errores te dan?

Comment: Ya lo he subido. Gracias por molestarte en comentar :)

Comment: Quita el operador de puntero `*` del `if` y ya podrás comparar valores de direccionamiento entre las variables `p1` y `p2`. Además, las variables booleanas deben ir en minúsculas, y tú tienes 3 referencias mal puestas. Éstas son: `TRUE` y  `FALSE` (deben ir en minúscula), y el retorno de la función debe ser `bool`, la primera letra también en minúsculas.

Comment: muchas gracias !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como bien dijeron, el casteo se debe hacer mediante `(struct nombre_struct *)p1`. Ahora, la comparacion `(struct nombre_struct *)p1 == (struct nombre_struct *)p2` posiblemente no esté haciendo lo que vos esperás.

Lo que estas haciendo al comparar un struct contra otro es ver si la direccion de memoria de cada estrucutra coincide. Estimo que lo que queres hacer en este caso es corroborar si algun campo o todos coinciden.

Algo por el estilo de:

```
Bool point_equal (const void *p1, const void *p2){

    if((struct tu_struct *)p1->a == (struct tu_struct *)p2->a){
        if((struct tu_struct *)p1->b == (struct tu_struct *)p2->b){
            if((struct tu_struct *)p1->c == (struct tu_struct *)p2->c){
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
    }
 
    return FALSE;
}
```

Y de yapa: No es necesario que uses else en el ejemplo que diste, ya que si se entra al if vas a retornar. Bien podrias haber hecho (y es mas optimo):

```
Bool point_equal (const void *p1, const void *p2){

    if(*p1 == *p2){
        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```